How to achieve better query performance to get matching records from huge tables in oracle
I have a main table in Oracle 12c with 50+ columns and over 10 million records. When I receive more data to be stored in this table (from UI into a Global Temporary Table), I first compare the data in global temporary table with the main huge table and mark the matching entries as 1 (using a MERGE statement with main table and global temporary table using all columns of these 2 tables as they have same columns).
This takes a lot of time, sometimes more than 3 minutes. I just need few pointers on any faster approaches for this type of requirement. I will explore any given ideas myself and if I find any breakthrough, I will share it on the forum.
*** Question Edited with more explanation below -

Table A is main table with 10 million (and growing) records.
Table B is GTT which may have different no. of records (ranging from
10 to 10K depending on new insert)
Doing a MERGE which will mark ID in GTT table (Table B) as '-1' for
all matching records (join on all columns).
Then insert the records from GTT table (Table B) into main table
(Table A) where ID is not equal to '-1' (only new records)
Table A has an index on only one column (cust ID) which is
irrelevant for this operation.

So, this is taking a long time and I am  trying to improve the performance here. Thank you once again.
Regards,
Sachin

What is it that you do with the data in the temporary table, and why do you need to mark the matching rows first?

Get the explain plan of the query, and update the question. Also, how many rows are in this temp table?

@Boneist - data in temporary table gets in from UI application (entered by users) which can range anywhere from 100 to 10000 rows. The process is first checking if any of these records already present in the main table and mark them (to avoid duplicate entries in the main table).

Why are you "marking the matching entries as 1" ?? An update of 10 million records is a lot of work. Do you really need to do that? Typically we'd only update a row if a meaningful attribute has changed. If you're using this to stage another step later on, don't. Combine the operations so you don't have do this expensive marking first.

@SachinVaidya Is there a relevant index that can be used to quickly match those 10K records to the 10M records? If so, check the explain or execution plan to ensure that an index is being correctly used by the MERGE statement. (You might also want to edit your question and add the details about the number of records, any indexes, and the plans.)

@Paul W - Apologies for late response as I was in laptop transition phase for last few days. I have edited the question for better clarity by adding more details. Sorry once again for earlier confusion.

@Jon Heller - Apologies for late response as I was in laptop transition phase for last few days. I have edited the question for better clarity by adding more details. Sorry once again for earlier confusion.

@SachinVaidya why not just do your MERGE statement directly from table B to table A, and only insert the non-matching rows?

We really can't solve performance problems without a lot more data: your SQL, the execution plan, where in the plan it's spending time, etc.. some of which is difficult to communicate in a forum like this.
But we can offer some general tips.

GTT = no parallelism. A global temporary table (GTT) has the advantage of being written to temp space rather than a normal datafile, which provides some streamlining (no redo, no delete/data cleanup at the end, etc..). However, it has one huge, major drawback: because rows in a GTT are visible only to the process that inserted them, parallel slaves cannot see them. For this reason, all PQ (parallel query) is disabled when working with GTTs. So that big merge against your target table? That's happening serially, using a single process, at most one CPU worth of muscle.

You would be better off, actually, staging those new rows in a real table (that you truncate before using) so you can enable PDML (requires enable_parallel_dml hint or alter session enable parallel dml plus a normal parallel hint in the merge) and perform that merge with some real power.
Alternatively, you can use normal PQ without PDML by prejoining to your target table within the USING clause of the MERGE statement, find new/changed rows only and feed back ROWID for use in the ON (...) clause. That expensive join is then part of a query block that can be in parallel even though the actual data block formatting at the merge step is serialized (but if you are loading a small number of rows each time, that's okay).


Look at your execution plan and determine if it's appropriate. If you are joining a few thousand rows to a table with 10 million rows (e.g. about 1/10th of a percent), then you probably should be using nested loops with an index on the join column. If it's not correct, you may need to create a missing index or hint the query to force its use. Also ensure this isn't a partitioned table with a local index and tons of partitions - that can really slow down index lookups. If on the other hand you were joining hundreds of thousands of rows to a 10 million row table, then a full table scan would be much better, in which case an index on the join column can cause a problem and may be best dropped. It all depends on the comparative size of the two inputs.

Examine ASH data (or ask your DBA for assistance) to ensure you have no concurrency issues (enqueues, busy buffer cache, library cache lock, etc..) preventing your work from proceeding. Ensure you have no trigger on the table you are modifying. Ensure there are no foreign keys on the table. These are all things that can really slow down DML. The only sure-fire way to tune SQL in Oracle with targeted accuracy is to examine the wait interface (ASH) and SQL Monitor (or tools that collect and present this raw data) to see exactly how (which waits) and where (in the plan) actual time was spent on an actual execution attempt. Any other approach is simply guesswork, hit-and-miss.

Lastly, don't split up an operation like this into unnecessary steps like marking the GTT first, then doing another operation based on those flags. That should be combined into a single operation with no row-marking done at all in tables.



Thank you for the suggestions. I am working on making some changes in the approach as this is a legacy code. I will update on the forum once I get a significant result.

Create an index on the huge table that will help match rows in the small, global temporary table. Pick a column, or a set of columns, with selective and non-null values. For example, index a unique ID column, not a Yes/No flag column.
(That's probably all you need. It seems like we've been collectively over-thinking this problem.)

The check for an existing record is happening by joining all columns of both (main huge table and the GTT table). Creating a new index (with that many columns) on an existing table with 10 million + rows might take forever. But I am trying few things, including your suggestions and hope to find a way ahead. Once again thank you very much for all the suggestions.

@SachinVaidya The index likely only needs to include a small number of columns. You just need to find a column or combination of columns that is relatively unique. If you have a unique identifier, that one column is good enough to help the join. If you only have less unique data, like FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME, then an index on only those two columns is still probably good enough.
